# HTML/CSS/Tables border are deformed when show / hide

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-tables

It is hard to me explain my problem but i will try,

1. Explanation

   I'm making a dynamic web with angularjs and jquery; then I have a array multidimensional is bigger, load  around 100 records, and I display it using table; each records have a hidden info and button (for launch the hidden/show function), this info should appears when user make a click in button, all work fine, the problem is when I show a hidden row, the columns below deform using google chrome but if I use Firefox all work fine, also I note when I use the developer tools of google and mark/unmark any background the view is corrected, so I think it's a browser error, that does not refresh the view as it should.
2. Pics

   Here is the list in normal view

   [image]

   and here when 1 hidden row is shown

   [image]

   [image]
3. CODE

   I think it's irrelevant place the code, because I try removing the AngularJS and using only jquery

   Nevertheless I prepared an example like as a work my app [`HERE IS THE PLNKR`](http://plnkr.co/edit/Usq6JzYVIXVAINwOP1eO?p=preview)

I hope you can help me

Comment: I open your plunker on chrome and works fine...

Comment: that plunker is only a example of the structure and functions used, in production are many data, many clases, and have this bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem, I checked the background color of the first column always remained fixed, so I thought it was a problem of position, looking at the property of this class (column 1), I saw appeared the `position: relative`, besides having many property `top bottom`, with the option !important

disabling all those options i fix the error